# Expose Car Hardware information

Tags: obd-ii, hyundai, computer

I am looking for way via which i can access my car information when it is running like speed,acceleration,gear information,oil information,etc .

My Car details : 
Hyundai Verma : Model 2006 , Manual Transmission , 1.6 petrol .

Comment: @Hennes is right in the follow up question ... Without some qualifying information, this might as well be a shopping question and will be closed.

Comment: @Paulster2: Please tell me what qualifying information you need , i will update that .

Comment: @Hennes: To be very frank nothing . I have been doing google search but couldn't get any information. I am newbie in automobile. Can you be suggest me what should i look for . Thanks for reply .

Comment: If you are looking to just tap into your ECU, then you can use an [ELM327](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELM327) device with free software. These can be had as a bluetooth device which will allow you to stream the information to a smart phone or tablet device and get the OBDII information you are seeking.

Comment: @Paulster2: i am trying to information like my car is in which gear right now , current speed , acceleration,load on engine,etc . It would be great if you can share your email id .

Comment: 1) The idea of this site is to get the information to a wide audience. Email is not the way for that.  
2) Google on ELM327 (or click Paul's link of it). You'll find that it is a very generic, widely used and cheap device which can all (or most?) or the things you asked, I got mine of amazon for about Eur 15.
3) Next look up your cars ODB-II/CAN ports in the manual (or google it).  Then try if you can see all you want with the ELM and some free software.( And if desired, buy some more capable software)>

Answer (score 1):

I recommend my combo, the app [Torque Pro](http://torque-bhp.com/) for display on a Bluetooth enabled phone or tablet, and a [Bluetooth ODBII Reader](http://www.amazon.in/ELM327-Wireless-Reader-Scanner-adapter/dp/B00C4QNBAO) like my BAFX Elm327 to get the data. Torque Pro has configurable on-screen real-time gauges. The data it can display is only limited by your vehicle's ODBII implementation.